# SherlockListFrgament with CommonsWare Loaderex, can't update data

Tags: android, sqlite, actionbarsherlock, android-cursorloader, commonsware-cwac

```
public class NewFriendsListFragment extends SherlockListFragment implements 
 LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

int monthchange, daychange;

Dialog dialog;

int pos;


CheckedTextView ctv_name;

private SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter=null;

private SQLiteCursorLoader loader=null;

String mCurFilter;

private static Handler responseHandler;


boolean loaded=false;

@Override 
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    //some more stuff...

    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    mAdapter = new FriendListSCA(getSherlockActivity().getApplicationContext(), 
            R.layout.friend_item, null,null, null, null, null, NAME),
            new String[]{NAME,MONTH,UID}, new int[]{R.id.name,R.id.info,R.id.profile_pic});
    setListAdapter(mAdapter);

    setListShown(false);

    registerForContextMenu(getListView());

    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);

    responseHandler = new Handler() 
    {                               
      //handler code
    };     
}



public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int loaderId, Bundle args) {
    //loader code
    return(loader);
  }

  public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
          mAdapter.changeCursor(cursor);

          // Showin List
          if (isResumed()) {
              setListShown(true);
          } else {
              setListShownNoAnimation(true);
          }
  }

  public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    mAdapter.changeCursor(null);
  }

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem item) {
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info;
    try {
        info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        return false;
    }
    pos=info.position;

    switch (item.getItemId()) {

    case R.id.edit_item:

            show_dialog();

        return true;
    }
    return(super.onOptionsItemSelected(item));

}

@Override 
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, final int position, long id) {      

            Log.e("onListItemClick","Inside onListItemClick");  
            ContentValues cv= new ContentValues();
//MORE CODE

            loader.update(TABLE_NAME_INCLUDE, cv, _ID+" = ?", new String[]{Integer.toString(position)});                

}



private class FriendListSCA extends SimpleCursorAdapter
{

public FriendListSCA(Context context, int layout, Cursor c,
        String[] from, int[] to) {
    super(context, layout, c, from, to,0); 
    setViewBinder(new FriendsListDataViewBinder()); 
}

}

public class FriendsListDataViewBinder implements SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder 
{ 
//_ID + "," + UID+","+NAME+","+MONTH+","+DAY+","+WISH
@Override 
public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor c, int columnIndex) 
{ 

    switch (view.getId())
    {
    case R.id.name:
        CheckedTextView ctv= (CheckedTextView)view;
        ctv.setText(c.getString(2));
        if(c.getInt(5)==0 || c.getInt(4)==-1)
        {
            ctv.setPaintFlags(ctv.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
            ctv.setChecked(false);
        }
        else
        {
            ctv.setPaintFlags(ctv.getPaintFlags() & (~ Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG));
            ctv.setChecked(true);
        }

        return true; 

    case R.id.info:

        if(c.getInt(4)!=-1)
        {
            ((TextView)view).setText(Utility.MONTH_NAME[c.getInt(3)-1] + " " + Integer.toString(c.getInt(4)));
        }
        else
        {
            ((TextView)view).setText("Tap and hold to manually enter");
        }
        return true;
    case R.id.profile_pic:

        if(!loaded)
            return true;

        ((ImageView)view).setImageBitmap(Utility.model.getImage(
                Long.toString( c.getLong(1) ), getURL(c.getLong(1)) ));

        return true;
    }

  return false; 
}
}

private void show_dialog()
{
//DATE PICKER CODE

 okay.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {  
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v)
         {
            ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
            cv.put(MONTH, monthchange);
            cv.put(DAY, daychange);
            loader.update(TABLE_NAME_INCLUDE, cv, _ID+" = ?" , new String[]{Integer.toString(pos)});
            //getLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, null, NewFriendsListFragment.this);
//I tried calling restart loader, but nothing, when I checked
//it turned out the sqlite database wasn't being updated

            responseHandler.sendEmptyMessage(1); //just dismisses dialog
         }
      });     
 dialog.show();
}



@Override 
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    // Place an action bar item for searching.
    MenuItem item = menu.add("Search");
    item.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_search);
    item.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
    View searchView = SearchViewCompat.newSearchView(getActivity());
    if (searchView != null) {
        SearchViewCompat.setOnQueryTextListener(searchView,
                new OnQueryTextListenerCompat() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String filtext) {
                mCurFilter = !TextUtils.isEmpty(filtext) ? filtext : null;
                getLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, null, NewFriendsListFragment.this);
                return true;
            }
        });
        item.setActionView(searchView);
    }
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

}
```

I'm using a SherlockListFragment from the ActionBarSherlock library to display a list using a CommonsWare Loaderex sqlite cursor loader, and evrything seems to work fine, the names and birthdays and profile pics are all displayed fine, but I can't seem to be able to update any of the data in the table using loader.update(...), nothing happens when I call it.
What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have:

```
loader.update(TABLE_NAME_INCLUDE, cv, _ID+" = ?", new String[]{Integer.toString(position)});
```

In all likelihood, that should be:

```
loader.update(TABLE_NAME_INCLUDE, cv, _ID+" = ?", new String[]{Integer.toString(id)});
```

(replacing `position` with `id`)

Comment: Lol, that had me baffled for over an hour. Thx so much^^